# Unexpected cout << from a string * when adding a comma

Tags: c++, string, cout

I'm having an interesting error upon moving over to g++ compiling on RedHat after using Visual Studio previously.

I have a loop that looks like this:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < data.size(); i ++){

    for(int j = 0; j < data[i]->size; j++){

        cout << data[i]->columns[j]<< ',';
    }

    cout << endl;

}
```

where data[i]->columns is  string  *, and the intent is to separate the output by commas.
Previously, this worked, however, today my output looks something like this:

```
,ata, two, three, four
,ata2, two, three, four
,ata3, two, three, four
```

Whereas if I change the code slightly to:
      cout << datai[i]->columns[j] << endl;

I get:

```
data
two
three
four

data2
two
three
four
```

What could be causing it to overlap these characters with commas? This wasn't occurring on the visual studio compiler.

Comment: Please copy-paste (*not* retype) *actual* code that demonstrates the error. The code snippet you posted isn't likely to compile. http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looked like the final entry in each row has a \r and/or \n.

So on four you get `"fourBREAK,"`

Your endl output seems to confirm this since you're getting 2 line breaks after four.

Comment: more specifically a carriage return character ('\r')

Comment: Looks like this is correct, setting the last character to null resolved the issue.

To rve- What exactly is the carriage return, and what causing it to become present? I was parsing the data using '\n' as a delimiter for the very string of a line, and figured it would not include the '\n' within the string itself.

Comment: @Glem Windows uses \r\n to represent a new line where Unix uses just \n. \r is a carriage return (to the beginning of the line) while \n is a new line. Think of it like a typewriter. First you have to move the bar back to the beginning, then you have to add a new line.

Answer (score 2):

Your input file (that you read when you populated `data`) is in MS-DOS text format. Either use `dos2unix` or a similar utility, or ignore `\r` on input.